# NSString pointer type warning

Tags: objective-c

I need to get a string value from an NSArray to populate a pop-up button with. This code populates the button, but I have a warning "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableString * _strong' from 'NSString *'.

```
for (NSObject * obj in availablePorts)
{
  result = [obj description];
  [portsButton addItemWithTitle:((NSString *)result)];
}
```

Comment: Note that you generally shouldn't use `description` for returning something that'll be shown to the user.

Comment: What's the better choice?

Comment: Typically, you'd have something like `displayString` or `portDisplayDescription` that would return the correctly localized variant of your object's user visible name.  `description` is typically for debugging and logging purposes only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` is a `NSMutableString*`. Your are trying to assign a pointer to `NSString` to a variable of type pointer to `NSMutableString`. Either change your declaration of `result`, or assign using `[[obj description] mutableCopy]` if you need an `NSMutableString`